# What's the term of $i^{n(3n-1)}$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, complex-numbers

$A=i^{n(3n-1)}$

$n=0$ then $A=1$

$n=1$ then $A=-1$

$n=2$ then $A=-1$

$n=3$ then $A=1$

$n=4$ then $A=1$

So how can simplified this in term general

Comment: The general term follows the pattern $1,-1,-1,1,\dots$. This can be proven using modular arithmetic.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  Look at the exponent modulo $4$

Comment: I think $i^{n(3n-1)}$ is the most neat and simplified form for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since $i^4=1$, it is enough to consider the exponent mod $4$. We get this periodic sequence:
$$
0,2,2,0, \dots
$$
Therefore, the original sequence is
$$
1,-1,-1,1, \dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

You could use Euler's formula: $$\begin{split}i^{n(3n-1)}
&=\left(e^{\pi i/2}\right)^{n(3n-1)}\\&=e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi in(3n-1)}
\\&=\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi n(3n-1)\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi n(3n-1)\right)\end{split}$$
and note that $(3n-1)-n=2n-1$ is odd, so one of $n$, $3n-1$ is even so $$\frac{1}{2}\pi n(3n-1)$$ will always be an integer multiple of $\pi$ so taking the sine of it always yields $0$, so $$i^{n(3n-1)}=\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi n(3n-1)\right).$$ Within a cosine, we can always subtract an even multiple of $\pi$ without changing it's value. Note that $2n^2\pi$ is an even multiple of $\pi$, so we can say that
$\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi n(3n-1)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi n(-n-1)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi n(n+1)\right)$ where the final equality follows from the identity $\cos x=\cos(-x)$. Now, we see that if $n\equiv 0\mod 4$ or $n\equiv -1\mod 4$, we take the cosine of an even multiple of $\pi$ which yields $1$. If $n\equiv 1\mod 4$ or $n\equiv 2\mod 4$, then we take the cosine of an odd multiple of $\pi$ which yields $-1$. In the end, we get
$$i^{n(3n-1)}=\begin{cases}1,&n\equiv0\mod4\\-1,&n\equiv1\mod4\\-1,&n\equiv2\mod4\\1,&n\equiv3\mod4\end{cases}$$ so the repeated pattern is $1,-1,-1,1,\ldots$.

Comment: If n=10 then ??

Comment: Then it's going to be $-1$, beceause $10\equiv2\mod4$.

Comment: But $i^{10×29}$=1?

Comment: No! We have $i^{290}=i^{288}\cdot i^2=(i^4)^{72}\cdot i^2=1^{72}\cdot (-1)=-1$.